# What is the best way to connect my Android client with a Java app server?

Tags: java, android, spring-boot

I have recently begun learning Android development and have written a Spring Boot Java application with REST using Spring MVC.

I would like some advice on how to connect to my server with an android client? Do I hit the REST controller using my android client?

What would you suggest is the best practice and what API would you recommend I use?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: First define "best"

Comment: if for "best" is the easiest way, try with Retorfit2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the requirement of application. There are several scenario where you want application & server communication.

1. **HTTP API call** 
   When front end application require some data from back end server or want to send some data to the server as part of application functionalities, then you can use any http client APIs like [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) or [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley)
2. **Websocket**
   If your application needs bidirectional continuos communication then you should pref to use [websocket-client](https://github.com/gusavila92/java-android-websocket-client) 

   In this case you need to create a socket end point at your back end server.
3. **Push Notification**
   Push notification is very obvious now days, If your server wants to deliver some data to your application, It is besically one way communication from server to client.

This explanation may help you to understand all possible scenario.

Comment: thanks..this was helpful @Afsar